# How to resolve "underlying connection was closed" in API

Tags: c#, api

I have an below json data.I am passing this json data from API using "PUT" method.The API returns response from postmen but when I run this api from below C# code then its shows an error message as ***"the underlying connection was closed"***

Please check the below code and advise how to solve this issue.

Json Data :-

```
[
  {
    "transaction": {
      "Version": "1.01",
      "TranDtls": {
        "TaxSch": "GST",
        "SupTyp": "EXPWOP",
        "RegRev": "N",
        "EcmGstin": null,
        "IgstOnIntra": null
      },
      "DocDtls": {
        "Typ": "INV",
        "No": "G/E/20-21/0175",
        "Dt": "11/09/2020"
      },
      "SellerDtls": {
        "Gstin": "29AAFCD5862R000",
        "LglNm": "K.H Exports India Private Limited",
        "TrdNm": "K.H Exports India Private Limited (Glove Division)",
        "Addr1": "142/,Trunk Road",
        "Addr2": "Perumugai",
        "Loc": "Via Vellore",
        "Pin": "560037",
        "Stcd": "29",
        "Ph": "04162253164",
        "Em": "edp.kharind@khindia.com"
      },
      "BuyerDtls": {
        "Gstin": "URP",
        "LglNm": "H M FINANCE AB",
        "TrdNm": "H M FINANCE AB",
        "Pos": "96",
        "Addr1": "MASTER SAMUELSGATAN 46 A,  106 38 STOCKHOLM SWEDEN  ",
        "Addr2": null,
        "Loc": "Sweden",
        "Pin": "999999",
        "Stcd": "96",
        "Ph": null,
        "Em": null
      },
      "DispDtls": null,
      "ShipDtls": {
        "Gstin": "URP",
        "LglNm": "LOGIX FZCO",
        "TrdNm": "LOGIX FZCO",
        "Addr1": "PO BOX 261422 PLOT NO. S21515, SOUTH BLOCK JEBEL ALI FREE ZONE DUBAI UNITED ARAB EMIRATES ",
        "Addr2": null,
        "Loc": "United Arab Emirates",
        "Pin": "999999",
        "Stcd": "96"
      },
      "ItemList": [
        {
          "SlNo": "0001",
          "PrdDesc": "FINE LEATHER GLOVES MADE OUT OF SHEEP LEATHER FOR LADIES. ",
          "IsServc": "N",
          "HsnCd": "42032920",
          "Barcde": null,
          "Qty": 10.0,
          "FreeQty": 0.0,
          "Unit": "PR",
          "UnitPrice": 452.50,
          "TotAmt": 4525.00,
          "Discount": 0.0,
          "PreTaxVal": 4525.00,
          "AssAmt": 4525.00,
          "GstRt": 0.0,
          "IgstAmt": 0.0,
          "CgstAmt": 0.0,
          "SgstAmt": 0.0,
          "CesRt": 0.0,
          "CesAmt": 0.0,
          "CesNonAdvlAmt": 0.0,
          "StateCesRt": 0.0,
          "StateCesAmt": 0.0,
          "StateCesNonAdvlAmt": 0.0,
          "OthChrg": 0.0,
          "TotItemVal": 4525.00,
          "OrdLineRef": null,
          "OrgCntry": null,
          "PrdSlNo": null,
          "BchDtls": null,
          "AttribDtls": null
        }
      ],
      "ValDtls": {
        "AssVal": 4525.00,
        "CgstVal": 0.0,
        "SgstVal": 0.0,
        "IgstVal": 0.0,
        "CesVal": 0.0,
        "StCesVal": 0.0,
        "Discount": 0.0,
        "OthChrg": 0.0,
        "RndOffAmt": 0.0,
        "TotInvVal": 4525.00,
        "TotInvValFc": 0.0
      },
      "PayDtls": {
        "Nm": "ABCDE",
        "AccDet": "5697389713210",
        "Mode": "Cash",
        "FininsBr": "SBIN11000",
        "PayTerm": "100",
        "PayInstr": "Gift",
        "CrTrn": "test",
        "DirDr": "test",
        "CrDay": 100,
        "PaidAmt": 10000,
        "PaymtDue": 5000
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Source Code :-

```
string DATA = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(trans2, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://einvoicing.internal.cleartax.co/v2/eInvoice/generate");

        request.Method = "PUT";
        request.Headers.Add("owner_id", "78c6beda-54a2-11ea-b064-0af3f8b02c24");
        request.Headers.Add("gstin", "29AAFCD5862R000");

        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.ContentLength = DATA.Length;



        StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
        requestWriter.Write(DATA);

        requestWriter.Close();



        try

        {

            WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();

            Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream);

            string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();

            Console.Out.WriteLine(response);

            responseReader.Close();
        }
catch()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the code you post does not contain any authentication data, especially considering you're also posting the endpoint you're trying to hit.

Have you tried installing Fiddler2 and watching what happens with the connection?

Does this endpoint expect a POST method instead of PUT?

Comment: No this api support only put method